# Replace several parts of URL using values stored in an array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, url, foreach

I am trying to automate a process of mine that involves fetching monthly reports that are generated on the first of each month for the previous month. The systems that generate these reports have different ways of distributing them, some are uploaded to an SFTP server, some are e-mailed as attachments, and the ones I am currently trying to fetch are stored on a web server.

Using some other code that I found, I have been able to authenticate to the web server at the URL one of the reports is hosted at, and I am able to successfully download the report.

Here is the code:

```
$request = Invoke-WebRequest $url -SessionVariable fb
$form = $request.Forms[0]
$form.Fields["username"] = "username"
$form.Fields["password"] = "password"
$downloadPath = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Reports_January_2019\File Servers\department1\"
$reportDate = (Get-Date -UFormat %b) + "01" + (Get-Date -UFormat %Y)
$url = "https://ourwebsite.com/schedule-reports/reportname/" + $reportDate + "/12-33-0-PM/servername1/monthlyreport.pdf"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($url + $form.Action) -WebSession $fb -Method POST -Body $form.Fields
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile ($downloadPath + "monthlyreport_servername1.pdf")
```

This code does work, so I am able to download the .pdf at the location specified. There are several other servers that the report is run on, so what I am trying to do is come up with an efficient way to download the reports generated for the other servers. For this, certain parts of the URL change. The parts that change are the date, the server name, and the name of the report which also has the server name in it. The `$reportDate` variable displays the dynamic part of the URL for the date the report was generated correctly.

I tried modifying this code and doing two `foreach` loops but this is where I am getting confused. Here is the code I am trying to make work to download all 7 reports using an array containing the server names:

```
$request = Invoke-WebRequest $url -SessionVariable fb
$form = $request.Forms[0]
$form.Fields["username"] = "username"
$form.Fields["password"] = "password"
$downloadPath = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Reports_January_2019\File Servers\$server\"
$servers = @("department1", "department2", "department3", "department4", "department5", "department6", "department7")
$serverNames = @("server1", "server2", "server3", "server4", "server5", "server6", "server7")
$reportDate = (Get-Date -UFormat %b) + "01" + (Get-Date -UFormat %Y)
$url = "https://ourwebsite.com/schedule-reports/reportname/" + "$reportDate" + "/12-33-0-PM/" + "$serverName" + "/monthlyreport.pdf"

foreach ($serverName in $serverNames) {
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($url + $form.Action) -WebSession $fb -Method POST -Body $form.Fields
    foreach ($server in $servers) {
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile ($downloadPath + "monthlyreport_$serverName.pdf")
    }
}
```

The result when I run this is that I get 7 .pdf files downloaded and they are all named appropriately (monthlyreport_`$serverName`.pdf), but the file size is 6KB for all of them and they can't be opened in a PDF reader because they are somehow corrupted. 6KB does not match the file size of any of the reports so something is definitely messed up. Additionally, they are not moved into their own folder as per the `$downloadPath` variable, but rather all 7 files end up in `"C:\Users\user\Documents\Reports_January_2019\File Servers\department7\"`

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be logical issues of variable expansion in some of your commands and variables. When you are outside of your loop trying to expand a variable that is assigned inside of a loop, you will only evaluate it once instead of every iteration of the loop. I do not know if the code below will get you the result you are looking for, but I know that it fixes the variable expansion problem.

```
$servers = @("department1", "department2", "department3", "department4", "department5", "department6", "department7")
$serverNames = @("server1", "server2", "server3", "server4", "server5", "server6", "server7")
$reportDate = (Get-Date -UFormat %b) + "01" + (Get-Date -UFormat %Y)

foreach ($serverName in $serverNames) {

    $url = "https://ourwebsite.com/schedule-reports/reportname/" + $reportDate + "/12-33-0-PM/" + $serverName + "/monthlyreport.pdf"
    $request = Invoke-WebRequest $url -SessionVariable fb
    $form = $request.Forms[0]
    $form.Fields["username"] = "username"
    $form.Fields["password"] = "password"

    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($url + $form.Action) -WebSession $fb -Method POST -Body $form.Fields

    foreach ($server in $servers) {

        $downloadPath = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Reports_January_2019\File Servers\" + $server + "\"
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile ($downloadPath + "monthlyreport_" + $serverName + ".pdf")
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not fix my issue, but your explanation does help and gives me some thinking points. When I ran this as-is, It downloaded all seven reports seven times each, and they were all in one folder.

I changed `$downloadPath` to be `$downloadPath = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Reports_January_2019\File Servers\$server\" ` and that ended up putting one of each report (for a total of seven) inside of each of the seven folders. All of the files still show as 6KB in size though and don't open in a PDF reader, so I've yet to figure that part of it out.